# Are questions with alternative metrics on topic?

Tags: discussion

Many/most questions are looking for how to do something, or how to do something faster.  I have a question where I know how to do something, and am happy with the speed, but want a solution that is short while being easy to understand, especially for relative newcomers to Mathematica.

```
In[20]:= {bins, counts} = N[HistogramList[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 2], 100]]]

Out[20]= {{0., 2., 4., 6., 8., 10.}, {13., 19., 37., 28., 3.}}

In[21]:= Transpose[{Riffle[bins, bins], Flatten[{0, Riffle[counts, counts], 0}]}]

Out[21]= {{0., 0}, {0., 13.}, {2., 13.}, {2., 19.}, {4., 19.}, {4., 37.}, {6., 37.}, 
          {6., 28.}, {8., 28.}, {8., 3.}, {10., 3.}, {10., 0}}
```

Is this too subjective for the site?

Comment: "Is there a simpler and/or more intuitive way of achieving this behavior?"

Comment: I'd say yes, go for it. @MikeBantegui 's phrasing is ideal.

Comment: @Mike: Can you make an answer out of your comment?

Comment: related but not duplicate: my [suggestion of a "elegant-code" tag](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176/8)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally, I strongly support questions like this.  I think they are very important to allow them.

There is less code sharing among Mathematica users than among "regular" programmers (C, Java, etc.), so there are fewer opportunities to get feedback on code, or to even develop a style that could be generally accepted as idiomatic (because non communicating much means everyone would come up with their own style and habits).

If we have a place to talk about these things, we will all become better Mathematica programmers.

Comment: I second this. Asking if there is a simpler way to achieve something is definitely on topic.